# Google page speed issue with "Prioritize visible content"

Tags: javascript, html, seo, google-pagespeed

In Google Page speed I receive a comment to "Prioritize visible content" this appears to be a recent change to the page speed algorithm. In order to try and understand the problem, I created a simple page with only one image and nothing else in the HTML (under my domain), and I still see the same message to "prioritize visible content."

The only way I found to eliminate the error was to convert the image to Base64 and place the image inside the HTML. I think this is not a good solution to the problem, as it will make the HTML heavy and slow the page down.

Are there any other suggestions to solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Usualy this issue shows when you have a lot of external javascript or css files needed by your page to render properly. The ideal solution that eliminates the issue is when you have images and css neded for "above the fold" part of your page placed inline in your HTML document. This allows browser to render visible part of the page immediatelly without making additional requests.

There are different ways how you can achieve this. One way is to load all your css and js asynchronously and inline part of css and js neded for "above the fold" area.

The reason why this issue appears in your test case could be that image takes comparable time to load to the HTML page itself.

You can read more about possible fixes in google documentation on this issue https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/PrioritizeVisibleContent?hl=en

Comment: This answer is basically a copy paste of what Google already includes in the Pagespeed report.